# Java sockets inputstreams outputstreams

Tags: java, sockets

**I have server:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        ServerSocket ses = new ServerSocket(7841);
        Socket s=ses.accept();

        Reader br = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        os.write("string from system".getBytes());
        os.flush();

        char[] request = new char[6];
        int count = br.read(request);
        while (count!=-1) {
            sb.append(new String(request, 0, count));
            count = br.read(request);
            System.out.println(count);
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
        System.out.println("111"+count);
        System.out.println(sb);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    System.out.println(sb);
```

**and client :**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",7839);
        Reader br = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
        os.write("string from project".getBytes());
        os.flush();


        char[] request = new char[6];
        int count = br.read(request);
        while (count!=-1) {
            sb.append(new String(request, 0 , count));
            // if (sb.toString().endsWith("</family>")) {
            //     break;
            // }
            count = br.read(request);
            System.out.println(count);
            System.out.println(sb);
        }
        System.out.println("111"+count);
        System.out.println(sb);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    System.out.println(sb);
```

The problem is I can not read the string till the end. For example, the server read only "string from projec".

Also the code `System.out.println("111"+count);` is not reached neither in client nor in server. What is wrong with the program? Thank you very much for any ideas.

Comment: I write to socket the string "string from system" and "string from project". System.output is used to check whether the following code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  program is fine, the only problem is your `Server` listening on port *7841*, but your client try to connect on the port *7839*, they  must connect to the same port.

I think you need to figure out the protocol things like:

1. Server starts to listen, there is no client yet, the server is waiting on method `accept()`;
2. When your client get connected, you must decide: who will first talk, who will response, what sign is beginning of the conversation and what sign is the end of the conversation, after this both the client and server can close this connection properly. Refer to this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html
3. If you don't like the request-response mode, you can read and write simultaneously, then maybe the thread approach is better, use two threads to separate reading and writing process, so the read process will not block the write process.

Back to your question, the read process blocks program in while loop, so the line `System.out.print(...)` can not be reached.

Comment: Thank you! The blocking is really an issue. When I remove reading from client and writing from server (or vice versa ) it works fine.